# Dúvida sobre "parent" no Jquery

Tags: jquery

Quero que quando eu clique na **class** `atendimento` a **class**`horarios` fique com `display:block`

Segue meu HTML:

```
<div class="margin-top-30 pai">
    <ul class="horarios">
        <li class="horariosFechar">x</li>            
    </ul>
    <div class="unidadesTotal">
        <div style="display:none" class="unidadesConteudo margin-top-25">
            <div class="atendimento unidadesAtendimento margin-top-15 f-left">hor&aacute;rio de atendimento</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

E meu JQUERY:

```
$( ".atendimento" ).click(function() {
    $(this).parent.parent.parent.find( ".horarios" ).css('display','block');
});
```

Ou seja, eu estou voltando com o `parent` para pode dar o clique, o que acontece, é que não está funcionando.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você se esqueceu dos parênteses depois do `parent`. Um alternativa para evitar essa quantidade de `parent` é usar [parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) da seguinte forma:

```
$(this).parents('.pai').find('.horarios').show();
```

Comment: Caraca, que noobisse a minha, tô até com vergonha, ahahaha. Era isso.

Comment: O `parents()` não funcionou.

Comment: também não. Todavia o `parent()` por si já funcionou

Comment: Como ele disse, tem que evitar usar essa quantidade de parent, Dependendo dos **parentes**es pode ser que um deles seja órfão. (risos)

Comment: Nem o código originalmente postado pelo OP e nem esse seu funcionaram como esperado. O dele pois executa uma rotina no clique de uma DIV oculta: Como ela vai ser clicada se está oculta? E o seu porque carece de contexto de disparo: Quando essa sua rotina será execuatda? No mesmo clique da DIV oculta? Sugiro revisar a resposta de, quem sabe, complementá-la